I have a population size of 500 and want to test X number of samples with high probability that I will catch a failure, how many samples do I test?
I cannot test all 500 subjects for failure. I need to know how many subjects out of the 500 I need to test in order to understand all subjects outcomes with confidence.
What would the formula be?

It depends on the failure rate.  Do you know, or assume, anything about that?  It also depends on what you might mean by "all subjects outcomes": would that refer to knowing the outcomes of all 500 subjects or would it mean estimating the failure rate among any untested subjects?

I think we could assume the failure probability $p$ (proportion of failure) in an answer.

If the population could have just a single failure, to have have an 80% chance of seeing it you'd need to sample 80% of the population; to have a 99% chance of seeing it, you would need to sample 99% of the population, and so on.

If the failure probability is $p$, the chance that you find no failures in $X$ independent tests is $(1-p)^X$. Determine the expected failure rate, the desired lower probability limit to find at least one failure, and solve for $X$.
If the failure rate is as high as 10%, you'll only need 29 cases to have a 95% chance of catching at least one failure ($0.9^{29}<0.05$). If the rate is 5%, you'll need 59 cases, and if the rate is only 1%, you'll need to sample 299 cases before having a 95% likelihood of finding one failure.
Note that this assumes that all failures are independent, the result of one test has no impact on the failure or success of another test. It also assumes an expected failure rate, rather having a priori knowledge of the actual failure rate among the population of 500. It would be possible (although fantastically unlikely) to have an expected failure rate of 50% and never find a single failure among all 500 cases, but if we know the actual failure rate among the 500 is 50%, we'd be guaranteed to find a failure in no more than 251 tests.

In a finite population, one ordinarily would not repeatedly test subjects for failure, whence no two results are independent, implying your solution is invalid.

In a production process, the same flaw in materials, machinery, method, environment, that makes one defect usually makes others. Intermittent failures are a different challenge.

What you are basically asking is about the confidence interval of a binomial proportion. It actually does not care about your populatin size (as long as it is "large enough")
It depends on 2 factors:

how confident do you want to be? E.g. if you want to be 95% confident, that implies that, with the chosen sample size, you will catch at least a failure, but 5% of the time, your sample will be "lucky", and not detect a failure.
what proportion of failures will you tolerate. E.g. if you can tolerate at least 5% failures in your population, then that proportion is 95%

It boils down to you being able to define how confident you want to be that at least a certain proportion of the population will be defect free.
For example, if you wan to be 95% confident that at least 95% of the population will defect free, you will need to test 56, w/o detecting a single failure. For 99% confidence, of 99% coverage, you would need to test 300 w/o a single failure...
If you encounter a failure during the test, you would have to test some more, to ensure the same confidence and coverage.
For learn more, search for Hypergeometric Distribution,

Although these points are good, it looks like you are doing all your calculations for a process (or, equivalently, sampling with replacement) rather than for the finite population specified. Differences start showing up once the computed sample size exceeds 10% or so of the population. For me this is important because I frequently sample fixed populations--of disputed insurance claims, of houses built within a subdivision, and so on--where (a) the cost of inspection is relatively high, (b) the stakes are high, and (c) the calculation will be scrutinized and has to be perfectly correct.

@whuber, I do fail to see how/why you came to the conclusion that the calculations are "for a process, or equivalently, sampling with replacement". This is not the case": yes, I mention testing 661 units, but that was a "jest"; the OP does not have 661 units, but only 500; so in that case, they will test all 500, find 1 failure, and now have certainty (no more stats!) that the population exactly contains 0.2% failures. But the calculations hold for finite populations which are large enough to accomodate the required sample size.

Because you have not explained how you arrived at these sample sizes and because your "jest" was presented seriously, I hope you will understand how any reader might be confused by this post.  Furthermore, I checked and found that the chance of failing to detect any population of size 500 with 1% = 5 defects with a sample of 458 is only 3.3E-6, demonstrating 459 is too big for 99% confidence and 99% coverage.  In fact, it is way too large: 300 will suffice.

@whuber, my computations are with the binomial distribution. Indeed, as the sample size gets large relative to the  population size, I should use the hypergeometric distribution (I got carried away). Yes, the sample size required for 99/99 is in fact 300 . And 56 for the 95/95 case... Thanks for the correction
